# Puppeteer: waitForFunction not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, puppeteer, ui-automation

I am using Node and Puppeteer.

I have an element that once I click it, text becomes "Generating" until download is finished. Once completed, text changes to something else. I am trying to poll to 1) verify the text switches to "Generating" (for verification) then 2) Poll until "Generating" is no longer present, indicating that it's finished and I can proceed. I have tried the following methods and none have seem to worked.

Although, I have tried all of these methods isolated (without being inside waitForFunction() and they all work. For example, verified document... works in console, etc.

Below is a couple of things I've tried (for the sake of brevity I'm not including the exhaustive list of others I've tried, many of which probably didn't even make sense but I was desperate). I am not including the 2nd step mentioned above since it's just an inverse of code below):

```
await page.waitForFunction('document.querySelector(#rptCol3A1Lnk0_txt).innerText.includes("Generating")')
```

I then attempted to use `$eval`, being a beginner with Node and Promises, I tried all combos I could think of with awaits and returns:

```
await page.waitForFunction((frame) => frame.$eval("#rptCol3A1Lnk0_txt", el => el.textContent.includes("Generating")),
        {timeout: 5000, polling: 300}, frame)
```

```
await page.waitForFunction(async (frame) => {
            return await frame.$eval("#rptCol3A1Lnk0_txt", el => el.textContent.includes("Generating"))
        },
        {timeout: 5000, polling: 300}, frame)
```

```
await page.waitForFunction(async (frame) => {
            return frame.$eval("#rptCol3A1Lnk0_txt", el => el.textContent.includes("Generating"))
        },
        {timeout: 5000, polling: 300}, frame)
```

The Puppeteer documentation is not super helpful for this method.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to scrape, but there could be easier methods especially if the page is updating you with results periodically. For instance if this is a web-socket event we could just skip right to proxying it and listening in on the messages.

Comment: @BGPHiJACK There is no scraping involved at this step, I am just trying to perform actions on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's in a frame you call it on the frame. Also you're quoting things wrong:

```
await frame.waitForFunction(() => document.querySelector("#rptCol3A1Lnk0_txt").innerText.includes("Generating"))
```

Comment: ah that was it! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If we're just wanting to see if the element's text has switched to "Finished" we can do something similiar:

```
 // Define a function that checks the element's text
  const checkTextChange = async () => {
    const element = await page.$('.your-element-selector'); // Replace with your element selector
    if (!element) return false; // Element not found

    const text = await element.evaluate((el) => el.textContent);
    return text === 'Finished'; // Check if the text has changed to "Finished"
  };

  // Wait for the element's text to change to "Finished"
  await page.waitForFunction(checkTextChange, { polling: 'raf', timeout: 30000 });
```

Not sure if this will help fully but it should be a start.

Comment: This is very helpful thank you. However, I am getting this error when running it: ```Uncaught Error: Passed function cannot be serialized!```